# Kotlin: Error de compilacion al añadir funcionalidad GPS a una aplicacion

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo un curso de kotlin, y la aplicacion que estamos desarrollando en el curso funcionaba bien hasta que empece a añadirle funcionalidad gps a la aplicacion. Uno de los muchos errores que da es el siguiente:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform common-31.2.0.jar (com.android.tools:common:31.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.

He buscado por todos lados y probado de todo, pero no consigo dar con la solucion. Si me podeis dar alguna pista os lo agradeceria. Incluyo los ficheros graddle.

graddle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript { repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral() }}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false }
```

y el graddle (app)

```
> plugins {
>     id("com.android.application")
>     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
>     id("com.google.gms.google-services") }
> 
> android {
>     namespace = "es.proyectoslore.cursoandroid.wildrunning"
>     compileSdk = 34
> 
> 
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId = "es.proyectoslore.cursoandroid.wildrunning"
>         minSdk = 21
>         targetSdk = 34
>         versionCode = 1
>         versionName = "1.0"
> 
>         testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
> 
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             isMinifyEnabled = false
>             proguardFiles(
>                 getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
>                 "proguard-rules.pro"
>             )
>         }
>     }
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>         targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     }
>     kotlinOptions {
>         jvmTarget = "1.8"
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
> 
>     //noinspection GradleCompatible
>     implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")//"androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
>     implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
>     implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
>     implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.3")
>     implementation("com.android.tools:common:31.2.0")
>     //com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0
>     implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
>     testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
>     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
>     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
>     implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))
>     implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
>     implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0")
>     implementation ("""com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.0""")
>     implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
>     //implementation ("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.20.0")
>     implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
>     implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0")
>     implementation ("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0")
>     implementation ("androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0")
> 
>     //para geolocalización
>     //noinspection GradleDependency
>     implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1")
> 
>    //seekbar circle, doc oficial
> https://github.com/tankery/CircularSeekBar
>     implementation ("me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.3.2")
> 
>     implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar")
>     // Facebook SDK Core only (Analytics)
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-core:16.2.0")
>     // Facebook Login only
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-login:16.2.0")
>     // Facebook Share only
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.15.3")
>     // Facebook Places only
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-places:5.15.3")
>     // Facbeook Messenger only
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:5.15.3")
>     // Facebook App Links only
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:5.15.3")
>     // Facebook Android SDK (everything)
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3")
>     // Audience Network SDK.
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0")
>     // Account Kit
>     implementation ("com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:5.4.0")
> 
> 
> }
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Al final quite estas lineas

implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.3")
implementation("com.android.tools:common:31.2.0")

Que eran las que me estaban causando el problema. Y compila, ahora la duda que tengo es si me va a fallar en el futuro porque alguna parte del codigo las necesite.